# Calculate normals using single face direction

Tags: modeling, normals

Could you calculate normals of an entire object referring to a single face to match up with ?

[image]

I have this model, some of this model's faces are just single faces.
Why some faces get flipped when others aren't?

And to my question, could you flipped all faces facing one direction to the same normal? The Normals' menu doesn't seem to help, and I have to go manually.

*well.. here is the example file: https://www.sendspace.com/file/7qfpoc*

Comment: The flip normals operator will flip the normals of selected faces.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes if there is a single face in the same object it behaves unexpectedly. So some will be red and some will be blue. Even after recalculating it is not uniform.